# Xcode 6-Keyboard Cursor Does Not Appear in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, ios-simulator

When I touch my textfields in the iPhone simulator, the keyboard cursor does not appear. I do not know why. These are the only functions related to my keyboard in my view controller.

```
 // hides keyboard when user touches outside of text field
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// hides keyboard when user presses 'return'
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if (textField === emailField) { 
        emailField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else if (textField === usernameField) {
        usernameField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `tintColor` property of your `UITextField` (for example, to the default `UIColor.blueColor`).

Comment: The hardware keyboard isn't active. The simulator keyboard pops up and works fine. I can type anything in the textfield. It's just that the cursor is invisible.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. Is the cursor visible when running on a device?

Comment: If not, try setting the `tintColor` of your `UITextField` to the default (`UIColor.blueColor`).

Comment: I changed my tintColor and the cursor appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the keyboard in your iPhone simulator is toggled off.

Try clicking,

Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard

Else on mac you can press Command K